# SQL Server 2014 restore .bak file

Tags: sql-server, restore

I am trying to restore a `.bak` file (might be created with SQL Server 2010) in SQL Server 2014 with this script

```
use master;
restore database [Vision] from disk = 'C:\Users\felix_000\Documents\Vision\db\Vision_db.bak'
with replace
```

and error log is as following:

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Directory lookup for the file "C:\SQLData\vision_newschema.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
>   Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>   File 'Vision' cannot be restored to 'C:\SQLData\vision_newschema.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>   Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Directory lookup for the file "C:\SQLData\vision_newschema_log.ldf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
>   Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>   File 'Vision_log' cannot be restored to 'C:\SQLData\vision_newschema_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>   Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I tried with right click `Tasks -> Restore -> Database`, it told me that

> Restore of database 'Vision' failed. BACKUP LOG cannot be performed because there is no current database backup. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Here are the methods I tried,

1. Run SSMS as administrator
2. change the file folder security property to FULL CONTROL

Comment: Is the SQL Server instance running on the same machine where that `C:\users\felix_000`  directory is located? The `.bak` file must be on the local disk **of the SQL Server machine** - not your machine (if you're trying to restore to a remote SQL Server) ....

Comment: Yes, I get it from other place but it now is on my machine. I tried to put this .bak file into sql server default backup folder, and still,  same problem

Answer (score 0):

Be sure That you are not trying to restaure an Entreprise Edition's Back up on an Express Edition.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do and getting the same error.  Is this not permitted?  Regardless of the size and versions?